# Why should I hire you?

Tags: interviewing

What is the best answer for why should I hire you? And what interviewer is expecting know. As I developer how should I answer this question so that It increase my hiring possibility.

Comment: You should give them a good argument for why they should hire you. We can't answer that, because we don't know why anyone should hire you ;)

Comment: Its a generic, vague question designed to make you come up with a sensible answer - outlandish answers are warning triggers, as are limp answers.

Comment: In my experience, that sort of question is automatically answered by an effective interview process.  If that cannot be figured out, its a flaw in the process.

Comment: An effective interview process includes open questions @SuperPomodoro. This one might not get the best out of every candidate or be appropriate for every position, but the manner of answering does demonstrate something useful to the interviewer.

Comment: I always say "I'll make you look good." Then elaborate, if asked but that's my personal style.

Comment: @Ben Any questions that can produce more signal and less noise are definitely effective.  In my experience, the "why should I hire you?" question has mostly produced noise.  I'm not against open-ended questions depending on the role, context in which it is being asked, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to show that you have paid attention so far. By that time you should be familiar with the company, the job and the requirements. Rattle through them one by one and check off where you are a good fit. Example

> "You are looking for an embedded C++ ninja and during my time at
>   company XXX I wrote a lot of high performance real time code in C++.
>   I'm happy to go through some benchmarks if you are interested."

Your answers should be specific to the job the company and yourself. Anything generic like "I'm a hard worker" or "I synergetically leverage key stakeholders" is useless.

It's also an opportunity to bring up any strengths that hasn't come up yet.

> "I also have a lot of experience in managing large data bases, which
>   may be helpful for your ABC project"

Answer (score 2):

This is an open question, there is no "correct" answer.

It's an opportunity to talk about your strengths and also show that you understood what they are looking for by telling them how your strengths fit their requirements.

Where the requirements fit, call it a great match. Where you are behind, call it a learning opportunity for you. If you feel they could profit from your superior knowledge in a field, tell them how they could profit from your knowledge.

If you share common culture, call it a good bonding opportunity. If you don't, call it a perfect chance to diversify the team and bring in new thoughts and fresh ideas.

Whatever you say, say it in a way that makes them think you are the best thing since sliced bread. But stay humble. Don't say it yourself, let them figure out that you are.